# Why on IOS the previous and next focus buttons in the virtual keyboard don't show the first time an input is focused?

Tags: ios, objective-c, focus, wkwebview, virtual-keyboard

The first time a web page is loaded inside a WKWebView, when an input is "focused", the virtual keyboard is opened. The first time only, the previous and next form field buttons are not visible.
When we focus another input, then the buttons are visible.

On the next picture you can see that the first input is focused but the previous / next buttons are not present in the keyboard.
[previous / next input element not present in the virtual keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/48fOB.jpg)

If the page reloads inside the web view, then the buttons of the virtual keyboard are displayed.
If you focus another input, then the buttons are visible:
[Focus buttons are now visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxI8j.jpg)

This problem is not linked to my web page, this problem happens on all web sites.

This problem also appears only on the WKWebView, with the UIWebView the buttons are always displayed and working.

To reproduce my problem, you can load a static web page inside a WkWebView with following content:

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="offline-form-ui">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <input type="text" name="test1">
    <input type="text" name="test2">
    <input type="text" name="test3">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is our objective-C code to load the page in the web view:

```
_webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero configuration:webConfig];
_webView.UIDelegate = self;
_webView.navigationDelegate = self;
self.view = _webView;

_webView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
_webView.scrollView.delegate = self;

NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"offline-form" ofType:@"html" inDirectory:@"www/ui"]];
[_webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

In that case we load files directly from the device, but the problem also occurs with online web pages.

Any help greatly appreciated.

**Update:** This seems to be a bug with IOS. I've created a simple project with only a WkWebView and the problem persists with any web site. I've created a new bug in the bug reporter of Apple.

Comment: Unfortunately this doens't change the behaviour

Comment: I got the same behaviour on google web site. My code is only here to help to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which version of IOS are you using ?

Comment: This problem only occurs inside a WebView, and only inside the WKWebView. You have to open the page inside an IOS app that includes a Web view to reproduce this problem.